# Multiple django projects with different domains on one server

Tags: django, apache

I am trying to run two different django projects one the same server, with two different domains. Django version is 1.8, and the webserver is Apache 2.4.7.
These are my conf files in sites-available:

```
#example.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com

  WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/path/example/WebPortal:/path/example/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup example.com
  WSGIPassAuthorization On
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/example/WebPortal/WebPortal/wsgi.py
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

  <Directory /path/example/WebPortal/WebPortal>
  <Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
  </Files>
  </Directory>

  Alias /robots.txt /path/example/WebPortal/static/robots.txt
  Alias /favicon.ico /path/example/WebPortal/static/favicon.ico
  Alias /media/ /path/example/WebPortal/media/
  Alias /static/ /path/example/WebPortal/static/

  <Directory /path/example/WebPortal/static>
     Require all granted
     Options -Indexes
  </Directory>

 <Directory /path/example/WebPortal/media>
     Require all granted
     Options -Indexes
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "/path/example/WebPortal/logs/webportal-error.log" 
  CustomLog "/path/example/WebPortal/logs/webportal-access.log" combined
  CustomLog "/path/example/WebPortal/logs/webportal-bandwidth.log" common
```

and:

```
#sub.example2.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sub.example2.com
  ServerAlias sub.example2.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example2.com

  WSGIDaemonProcess sub.example2.com python-path=/path/sub_example2/WebPortal:/path/sub_example2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup sub.example2.com
  WSGIPassAuthorization On
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/sub_example2/WebPortal/WebPortal/wsgi.py
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

  <Directory /path/sub_example2/WebPortal/WebPortal>
  <Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
  </Files>
  </Directory>

  Alias /robots.txt /path/sub_example2/WebPortal/static/robots.txt
  Alias /favicon.ico /path/sub_example2/WebPortal/static/favicon.ico
  Alias /media/ /path/sub_example2/WebPortal/media/
  Alias /static/ /path/sub_example2/WebPortal/static/

  <Directory /path/sub_example2/WebPortal/static>
     Require all granted
     Options -Indexes
  </Directory>

 <Directory /path/sub_example2/WebPortal/media>
     Require all granted
     Options -Indexes
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "/path/sub_example2/WebPortal/logs/webportal-error.log" 
  CustomLog "/path/sub_example2/WebPortal/logs/webportal-access.log" combined
  CustomLog "/path/sub_example2/WebPortal/logs/webportal-bandwidth.log" common
```

With this configuration when I enable both, only one domain work properly...on the other one I get a Bad Request (400).
I have tried many options but no one work.
Any ideas?

Comment: why do you have `<*:80>` and not `<yourdomain.com:80>` ?

Comment: You have to use NameVirtualHost: see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: @Daniel When I use NameVirtualHost i get this:  `AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release` probably cause I use apache 2.4. @Eduard I have tried to use `<yourdomain.com:80>` but it doesn't work